# Assembly division error

Tags: assembly, divide-by-zero

Please explain me, why i get "Divide by zero" error for this code:

"mov ax,300

mov bl,2

idiv bl"

It should be as follows: al = ax div source, ah = ax mod source

Answer (score 2):

`idiv` is signed division which produces quotient in `al` as you said. That is a 8 bit register and `300/2=150` which does not fit into 8 bits when using signed arithmetic (since the maximum is `127`). Somewhat misleadingly, you get `divide by zero` for overflow too (it's actually called `#DE divide error`). This is of course written in the instruction set reference.

You can use `div bl` if you are happy with an unsigned calculation, in that case `150` fits into `al` and you won't get an error.